# on cascade delete on a table with two FK to the same table

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, cascade

I have a relation called `Friends` with the following columns,

```
User1ID   
User2ID
Since
```

`User1ID` and `User2ID` are a set of primary keys in the relation. They are also foreign keys referencing to the table Users. Now i want to add an `ON CASCADE DELETE`, such that when a user from table Users is deleted then the corresponding row from table `Friends` is deleted as well. However, MS SQL Server does not allow me to add that constraint.

Any ideas, about how can i modify the table, in order to accomplish that task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't have multiple or circular cascade paths: it becomes ambiguous what you want to do (say one CASCADE NULL and the other CASCADE DELETE)

I'd use a stored procedure to delete from `Friends` first in a transaction then from `Users` (in a TRY/CATCH of course to deal with errors)

```
BEGIN TRAN
   DELETE Friends WHERE User1ID = @UserID;
   DELETE Friends WHERE User2ID = @UserID;
   DELETE Users WHERE UserID = @UserID;
COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i believe that this approach is much better. Thanks again!!